# Python reverse quicksort

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I have a working quicksort algorithm which sorts strings and integers into ascending order, however I need to be able to change it to swap to a descending sort and back at will. Simply changing the signs did not work. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated, I have included the relevant segment:

```
        while left_pointer <= right_pointer and \
            items[left_pointer] <= pivot_pointer:
            left_pointer += 1

        while items[right_pointer] >= pivot_pointer and \
            right_pointer >= left_pointer:
            right_pointer -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The equality operator for the *comparison of the values* should be reversed; don't switch the signs. Left is still left, right is still right.

Why does this work? Well, consider a sort function that takes a predicate, `sorted(lst, cmp=f)`. When `f` is `lambda a,b: a >= b` the sort is ascending and when it is `lambda a,b: a <= b` it is descending.

So where is "f" in the sort code? Well, it is here:

```
while leftmark <= rightmark and f(items[leftmark], pivotvalue):
      leftmark += 1

# note the argument order is reversed so that the same "f"/equality is used
while f(pivotvalue, items[rightmark]) and rightmark >= leftmark:
      rightmark -= 1
```

Thus those are the two places (where "f" occurs) that the comparison should be reversed to change the sort order - alternatively, leave in `f` and supply an appropriate function.